# Adding a domain suffix to the DNS search in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, netplan

I have a laptop running 20.04, and wish to be able to address hosts on my network by just their hostname, instead of having to specify the full fqdn every time. The following is my current /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml, which doesnt seem to work

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlp2s0:
    
      nameservers:
        search: [intern.kepp.tech]
        addresses: [192.168.0.6]
```

What am I doing wrong here?
The following output illustrates my problem:

```
    root@KTLAPTOP01:~# nslookup klwks01
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find klwks01: SERVFAIL

root@KTLAPTOP01:~# nslookup klwks01.intern.kepp.tech
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   klwks01.intern.kepp.tech
Address: 192.168.0.23
```

Comment: Do you have an internal DNS server for that domain? What is being used as DHCP server - your router or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have an internal  Windows Server 2019 DNS server for that domain. DHCP is done by my Internet Router. DNS for kepp.tech is managed by an external provider.

Comment: Have you tried updating the "Search domains" in the Network Manager with your domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlp2s0:
    
      nameservers:
        search: [intern.kepp.tech]
        addresses: [192.168.0.6]
```

should read

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlp2s0:
    
      nameservers:
        search: ['intern.kepp.tech']
        addresses: [192.168.0.6]
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Also, the installer creates this file incorrectly - doesn't indent "search" properly; have to fix the file in text editor after installation.